# SQL – count records from one table, using date range of a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count

So let’s say I have tables – Actions and Records that look like this:

Actions TABLE:

```
 
action_id  customer    start_time        end_time
101         A          2016-01-01 15:00  2016-01-02 15:00
102         B          2016-01-01 15:00  2016-01-01 20:00
103         A          2016-01-01 23:00  2016-01-02 23:00
```

Records TABLE:

```
 
rec_id  customer          time        
1001       A         2016-01-01 16:00 
1002       A         2016-01-01 20:00 
1003       A         2016-01-02 17:00 
1004       B         2016-01-01 15:50
```

I want to count all the records in the second table that happened within the start_time and end_time of the 1st table, and  group it by action_id, customer.

my expected output should be:

```
 
action_id  customer    count (rec_id)        
101       A               2 
102       B               1
103       A               1
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: And you have tried **what?**

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 
    a.action_id,a.customer,count(*) as cnt
    from
    records r
    join
    Actions  a
    on r.customer=a.customer and 
   r.time between a.start_time and a.end_time
   group by  a.action_id,a.customer
```

Comment: thanks, however the end result is disregarding the time criteria (even though we defined it)    
so I get , using my previous example, Customer A - cnt: 3, for both action_id: 101 and 103